False error: <Html> should not be imported outside of pages/_document
First off, I'm aware that this question was recently asked but that solution didn't work for me.
I'm getting the error <Html> should not be imported outside of pages/_document., but I'm NOT using the <Html/> component anywhere else. This is a fresh new Next.js project I just created yesterday using create-next-app.
In the other question, the solution was to set NODE_ENV=production but mine already is, so clearly it's a different issue.

Just posting this answer until someone else has a better solution. I kept downgrading by minor versions one at a time until it worked. 13.4.2 was the magic version where this error does not occur for me.
Edit: Nevermind, TailwindCSS does not work anymore when I do this so this is not a solution for me.
